# Problem copying images to backup directory

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a problem when I need copy some png and gif images in a directory.

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

TYPEA="png"
TYPEB="gif"

read -p "Say a directoy" $DIRECTORY

find ~/*.$TYPEA -size +10000k -exec cp -r $DIRECTORY {}\
find ~/*.$TYPEB -size +10000k -exec cp -r $DIRECTORY {}\
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last two commands are unterminated, and you are trying to copy $DIRECTORY into the files... which is surely not what you want. Also, please quote your variables...

I *think* you are looking for files with .gif and .png extensions in `~` over a certain size, which you want to copy to DIRECTORY... in which case it would be better to ditch the assignment of TYPEA and TYPEB in your script and just do:

```
find ~ -iname "*.png" -size +10000k -exec cp -r '{}' "$DIRECTORY"  \;
find ~ -iname "*.gif" -size +10000k -exec cp -r '{}' "$DIRECTORY" \;
```

or better

```
find ~ -iname "*.png" -size +10000k -exec cp -r '{}' "$DIRECTORY" +
find ~ -iname "*.gif" -size +10000k -exec cp -r '{}' "$DIRECTORY" +
```

if you expect a lot of results.